# What is the Turkish village shown in this video?

Tags: turkey, identify-this, where-on-earth

- [People Living in the Village - Village Documentary](https://youtu.be/7OLRjtfb_iU)

I can guess that this is a village in Turkey.

But, I want to know the exact location.

Can anyone tell me where this place is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is located in [Kargı](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Karg%C4%B1,+%C3%87orum,+Turkey/@41.13453,34.4871551,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipMCpMM2v3hXwj6iP3OP8qTsOHujymGoa-gJzhZb!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMCpMM2v3hXwj6iP3OP8qTsOHujymGoa-gJzhZb%3Dw129-h86-k-no!7i1299!8i864!4m5!3m4!1s0x4084259a998e06cf:0x5772f92d3efdc5bf!8m2!3d41.13453!4d34.4871551), Çorum Province, North of Turkey.

Comment: Maybe elaborate a bit on how you found it? Always interesting to learn new little tricks.

Comment: @MaxD I read the YouTube comments. Oldest trick around...

Comment: @MaxD He is the cow farmer in the picture. :P

Comment: @JoErNanO you caught me 